Can I invoke xtrace to attach to an already running process
In bash scripts I sometimes use a command of the form
xtrace -o xtr.txt 2> /dev/null command-of-interest

to obtain info about 'command-of-interest' that is otherwise unobtainable. But this starts command-of-interest within xtrace. I now have the condition that command-of-interest is already running as a child process within another script, and I would like to be able to attach xtrace to that child process (without upsetting the parent script). Is this possible with xtrace?
strace does offer this as an option by supplying it the pid of the running command-of-interest, but unfortunately strace does not provide the info I need here.
